# Testing Directives events

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, karma-runner

I have a directive that $emit's an event, but in the parent scope of a unit test doesn't get the event.

test $broadcasts an event to the directive, directive gets the event, and then directives $emits its own event, that the parent should get.

unit test:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    compile = $compile;
}));

element = compile(angular.element('<div myDirective></div>'))(scope);
scope.$digest();

var _scope = element.isolateScope();
scope.$broadcast('directive-change');
scope.$on('directive-successfully-changed', function (e) {});
```

directive:

```
 scope.$on('directive-change', function (e) {
    scope.$emit('directive-successfully-changed');
 });
```

Comment: The way I read your code, you're setting the `scope.$on('directive-successfully-changed')` into the directive isolated scope, not a parent. And, what is the purpose of the `_scope` variable (with underscore) ?

Comment: _scope is the scope of a directives controller. I have used rootScope for broadcasting and $on events, and it did not fix the problem

Comment: Could you try to invert your `$broadcast` and `$emit` please?